# I get a garbage value when trying to find the sum of array

Tags: c

I tried defining a large number by #define, that didn't work.

```
int main() 
{   
    long *N;
    N = (long *)malloc(10^10 * sizeof(int));
    int n = 0, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    //long N = 10 ^ 10;
    //int size[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%lu",(N + i));
        sum = sum + *(N+i);
    }
    printf("%d", sum);

    free(N);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `10^10` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? `10^10` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It's the [bitwise XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR)

Comment: You are missing `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do? I understand you want to allocate memory for 10 to the power of 10 integers. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the previous answer ^ is a XOR operator. I guess your intention is to allocate memory for 10 power 10 number of integers. Its physically not possible to allocate such huge memory. Try something like

N = (long *)malloc(1000 * sizeof(long));

This may work :)

Answer (score 2):

`^` is a bitwise XOR operator.  The result of `operator^` is the bitwise XOR value of the operands.

`10^10 * sizeof(int)` is `10^ (10*4)` because of precedence rules and will result in 34 bytes being allocated.

And if the value of `n` is greater than 8, you will end up accessing memory that is out of bounds for your program in the following statement.

```
scanf("%lu",(N + i));
```

To avoid this, you can first read into `n` and then use `malloc` like this:

```
malloc(n * sizeof(int))
```